# Rails6 - PurgeCSS ignores styles from image_pack_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, tailwind-css, css-purge

I'm following the TailwindCSS screencasts, railsifying them as I go.

I have uncommented the image_pack lines in a/j/p/application.js:

```
const images = require.context('../images', true)
const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
```

and can successfully pull images from a/j/images/ using image_pack_tag in an erb file.

however, when I use purgecss on the resulting files, purgecss does not keep the css classes need to properly style the image.

For example, a static image link works:

```
<img src="/images/beach-work.jpg" class="mt-6 rounded-lg shadow-xl">
```

but when accessed via image_pack_tag:

```
<%= image_pack_tag "beach-work.jpg", class: "mt-6 rounded-lg shadow-xl" %>
```

styling is not retained.

*How should I fix this?*

Answer (score 0):

You can do a few things:

- whitelist the classes in purgecss options

```
whitelist: [
  'mt-6',
  'rounded-lg',
  'shadow-xl'
]
```

- add a commented out static version of the code.  This worked in slim for me, erb for your example should be:

`<%# <img src="" class="mt-6 rounded-lg shadow-xl"> %>`